# How do I get total record count from Doctrine_Pager?

Tags: php, doctrine

I am tryign to use Doctrine_Pager for the first time. So I have the following code.

```
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->from("Member m");


    $pager = new Doctrine_Pager($q,1,10);
    $result = $pager->execute();
```

I need to know total record count of Member table. How do I get it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it myself.

$pager->getNumResults() returns the value.